# SearchBox in WPF

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, xaml, search

I have a textbox on Home.xaml window with the following code.

```
<TextBox Name="txtSearch" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" 
         Grid.ColumnSpan="2" FontSize="25" Height="50px"
         Width="480px" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
</TextBox>
```

The text written by the user is used on the following query:

```
SELECT Books.ISBN, Books.Title, Books.Tag, Books.Image, 
       Books.photoType, Publishers.Name AS publisherName
FROM   Books 
INNER JOIN Publishers ON Books.codPublisher = Publishers.codPublisher
WHERE (Books.Title LIKE '%' + @Title + '%')
```

The returned rows fills a DataGrid on another window.

The search works by book title and author, but there is a problem. Take for instance the book "Windows Server 2008 R2 Unleashed".

If the user searches for "windows" or "server 2008" or "windows server" it works. But if the user searches for "windows 2008" it doesn't.

Comment: To do that kind of search you need to separate the search string into tokens, and query that every token is included in the title

Comment: Hi, if I could take the input text and replace the spaces with %, maybe it could work, but I don't know how.

Comment: Hi, I just looked into the string.replace method and I replaced the spaces for % and now it works.    search = txtSearch.Text.Replace(" ", "%")

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: @CarlosSota Would you expect "Windows 2008 server" to return the same results?

Comment: @John Sauders, roger that!

Comment: @D Stanley, yes I would. It doesn't work this way does it?

Comment: What database are you using? If SQL Server look into 'Full Text Searches' (other databases possibly have a similar feature)